# How many boxes do you need to open to find 4 spoiled oranges with a minimum of 90% probability?

Tags: probability

I'm new to probability and I got this question that I'm not sure how to go further with:

There are 50 boxes, each containing 48 Oranges, and out of all those Oranges, 72 are spoiled. The numbers given above can be considered generally, for any box of Oranges and the number of the spoiled oranges is equally distributed among the boxes.

i) What is the probability that a box contains exactly 4 spoiled oranges?

ii) How many boxes do you need to open, in order to find a box containing exactly 4 spoiled Oranges, with a minimum probability of 90%?

So for part 1, $ 50 \times 48 = 2400$  is the number of total oranges, which means $\frac{72}{2400} = 3$% is the percentage of spoiled Oranges in general. I assume that means that an orange has a probability of 3% of being spoiled, and 97% of being good.

Furthermore, a box has 48 Oranges, so the chance of finding a box with exactly 4 spoiled oranges is $P_n = 0.03^4 \times 0.97^{44} = 2.12 \times 10^{-7}$, is this correct, or should it be $0.03^4 + 0.97^{44}$?

For the second part, I first got the complement probability, that a box doesn't contain 4 spoiled Oranges $P_x = 1 - P_n$. My idea was that if I keep raising that to the power of n, I need to count how many times "I open the box (power of n)" until the result gets below 0.1 and then I take the total number of boxes and subtract this n. However, in this case $P_x$ is so close to one that raising it to any power of n, changes nothing. This method only worked if I used addition instead of multiplication for $P_n$ above. My $n$ was 8 in that case.

I am not sure if my idea is the right idea. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are missing the binomial coefficient.  $P_n= {48\choose n} (0.03^n)×(0.97^{48-n}), P_4 = {48\choose 4} (0.03^4)×(0.97^{4})$

Comment: I need it because otherwise my original formula calculates the probability that 4 specific Oranges are spoiled? I mean, do you need to put the binomial coefficient in order to generalize such that any 4 oranges in a box can be spoiled?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Ah I see makes sense. Intuitively it didn't make sense to make the way I was calculating it, since I felt like I was calculating the probability that the first 4 were spoiled, but that's not exactly what I wanted. Thanks for clearing that up.

Regarding the second part though, once I figure that 'n' for the compliment probability Px, is that the number of boxes I need to at least open? Or is it then 50 - n (since the n I found was for the compliment probability)?

Comment: For part 2, the approach you suggest will work.  The probability that you find four rotten oranges in the $n^{th}$ box.  Means you did not find them in the first $n-1$ boxes.  If $B_n$ is the probability that the $n^{th}$ box is the first box with 4 rotten oranges $B_n = p (1-p)^n.  E[X] = \sum nB_n$  And this is a convergent series.  However, it is a little bit of a let down when you see that the sum of the series is $\frac {1}{p}$

Comment: Ah I see. Well thank you very much for your help! Have a good day/night!

Answer (score 2):

For part (i), a given box contains $n = 48$ oranges.  The probability that exactly $X = 4$ of these are spoiled is a binomial probability, i.e., $$\Pr[X = x] = \binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x},$$ where $p = 0.03$ is the probability of a single randomly selected orange being spoiled.

For the second part, let $\theta = \Pr[X = 4]$, which you computed in the first part.  This is the chance that a single randomly selected box contains exactly $4$ spoiled oranges.  The probability that exactly $N$ boxes need to be opened in order to obtain a box with exactly $4$ spoiled oranges is a geometric probability, i.e., $$\Pr[N = n] = (1-\theta)^{n-1} \theta, \quad n = 1, 2, \ldots.$$  Thus, you wish to find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $\Pr[N \le n] \ge 0.9$.  We note that $$\Pr[N \le n] = \sum_{k=1}^n \Pr[N = k] = \sum_{k=1}^n (1-\theta)^{k-1} \theta = \theta \frac{1 - (1-\theta)^n}{1-(1-\theta)} = 1 - (1 - \theta)^n.$$  Therefore, we can explicitly solve for $n$:  $$0.9 \le 1 - (1 - \theta)^n$$ implies $$n \ge \frac{\log 0.1}{\log (1 - \theta)},$$ for which the minimum such $n$ is $$n = \left\lceil \frac{\log 0.1}{\log (1 - \theta)} \right\rceil.$$

---

We should also consider the case where the oranges and boxes are finite in number as described by the problem, and that the distribution of the $72$ spoiled oranges is equiprobable among the boxes.  Then we can intuitively see that there is a nonzero probability that **none** of the boxes contains exactly four spoiled oranges.  What is this probability?  We can perform quick simulations to this end; on $10^6$ such simulations, I obtained the following empirical distribution of the number of boxes $Y$ with $4$ spoiled oranges: $$\begin{array}{c|c}y & \Pr[Y = y] \\ \hline
 0 & 0.099538 \\
 1 & 0.265719 \\
 2 & 0.307941 \\
 3 & 0.207353 \\
 4 & 0.088556 \\
 5 & 0.025168 \\
 6 & 0.004962 \\
 7 & 0.000691 \\
 8 & 0.000067 \\
 9 & 0.000005 \end{array}$$
Now, if we assume that we choose boxes at random without replacement, and stop at the first box containing $4$ spoiled oranges, we get the following plot of the empirical distribution of the number $N$ of boxes opened (again on $10^6$ simulations):
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the very extensive answer! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is an exercise in the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  The chance of four bad oranges in one box is ${48 \choose 4}0.03^40.97^{44}$ because you choose the four oranges to be bad, then multiply the probabilities that those oranges are bad by the probabilities that the others are good.  This is a much larger chance than you calculated, which will change the answer for the second part.  You are thinking in the right direction for that one.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out now thanks to you and the other people who answered. :)

Answer (score 1):

The probability that a box contains exactly four spoiled oranges, if we're assuming that a particular orange being spoiled is simply a $3\%$ probability event, would be given by $0.03^4\times 0.97^{44}\times\binom{48}{4}$. If you don't include the binomial coefficient, you're calculating the probability that the *first* four oranges are spoiled, and the rest are good. Since it could by any set of $4$, we need to multiply by $\binom{48}{4}$, the number of size-$4$ subsets.

That calculation comes out to about $4.126\%$, which means the second part of your calculation will work out differently, taking the complement and raising it to powers. You don't want to use addition in the second part.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot more sense! Thanks a lot. I'm still getting my head around probability and combinatorics. I've only had it for 2 weeks so far. 

Regarding the second part though, once I figure out the power for the compliment, is that my answer or would I need to subtract that from the total number of boxes? I've been squeezing my head trying to visualize it, but I couldn't figure out which answer it would be.

Comment: If we're thinking about it the same way, then you *don't* subtract from the total number. The probability of *not* finding your $4$ on the first box is $1-P_4$. The probability of *not* finding your $4$ after $k$ boxes is $(1-P_4)^k$. When that's less than 0.1, then the probability of *yes* finding your $4$ in that many boxes is over $90\%$. At that point, $50-k$ would be the number of boxes still unopened when you've opened enough to get your probability over $90\%$.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. I was just a bit confused, since at first, with my wrong answer, the number of boxes it took to get to 10% was 8, which was too small to make sense, hence why I thought you need to subtract. But now it makes sense. My new n = 55. I need to open at least 55 boxes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting $55$, too, which is kind of funny, seeing as there are only $50$ boxes. I think it's the correct answer, though. It turns out having a $3\%$ event happen $4$ times in a sample of $48$ just isn't very likely.

Comment: The question was in German, I had to translate it for this post, so some words might have gotten lost in the translation. But I think it's correct, since in the question they talk about a supermarket delivery of oranges, and they say, that you can generalize all of the data from that last delivery.  I think the amount of boxes and such is just a way to make us work a little bit to get those basic probabilities at the start... Rather than just saying the probability of an orange being spoiled is 3%.